# Eclipse RCP: How to add a new element to a default Java dropdown menu in the toolbar(New Java Class)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm making an RCP application. I need to change the 'New Java Class' dropdown menu:

[image: Dropdown menu]

to have an extra element (it is used to create a new custom application).

Also I need to change the default 'New Java Class' button to this new custom application element.

I couldn't find the required IDs to extend this dropdown menu in the plugin.xml. My current solution is to create a completely new menuContribution in the toolbar and somehow hide the old one. But I think it should be possible to add a new command to the already existing one.

Comment: Please add the images to the question rather than just the link. Links may break in the future.

Comment: It said I needed 10 reputation points to post images.

Comment: @fmorva Did you try using Eclipse Spy to inspect the dropdown?

Comment: @GGrec yep, it returned the following:
The active contribution item identifier:
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.NewTypeDropDown
The active action set identifier:
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementCreationActionSet

Sadly I wasn't able to spy the elements inside the list itself. Also I don't really know what to do with the above information, how to extend it with a new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That drop down menu is implemented by the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewTypeDropDownAction` class.

The code reads through the list of New Wizards declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point. Only new wizards which declare the `class` using a child element which itself includes a `parameter` child element with a value of `javatype` are used.

This is the 'Interface' wizard declaration using this format:

```xml
<wizard
    name="%NewJavaInterface.label"
    icon="$nl$/icons/full/etool16/newint_wiz.png"
    category="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java"
    id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewInterfaceCreationWizard">
  <class class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewInterfaceCreationWizard">
     <parameter name="javatype" value="true"/>
  </class>
  <description>
     %NewJavaInterface.description
  </description>
   <keywordReference id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.java"/>
</wizard>
```

The

```
  <class class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewInterfaceCreationWizard">
     <parameter name="javatype" value="true"/>
  </class>
```

section is the part that the drop down is looking for.

This format doesn't actually seem to be documented in the Eclipse help.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick help, it worked perfectly! Do you know how to change the default "New Java Class" button next to the downward pointing arrow to this new custom element?

Comment: Also, is there a way to change the order of the wizards? Currently the new custom wizard became the first one in the dropdown menu. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The default action can't be changed. The order just seems to be the order the new wizard extension point declarations are found.